# Inline formset for creating new objects with one-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

**models.py:**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ItemImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item_pics')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='images')
```

With the above defined models, `Item` has a one-to-many relationship to `ItemImage`. I am working on a django form that enables user to create a new `Item` instance, along with the choice of uploading up to two `ItemImage`. Note that the `Item` and the associating `ItemImage` objects need to be created at the same stage.

**forms.py:**

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    img_1 = fields.ImageField()
    img_2 = fields.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'circles', 'location', 'rental_fee', 'rental_time_unit', 'deposit', 'rental_rules',)
```

On a second thought, instead of adding the image fields to `ItemForm`, I am guessing it might be a better approach to create a `ModelForm` for `ItemImage` and use **inline formset**. I have never used inline formset and thus my concept of it is still vague. I want to know if this is a right scenario to use inline formset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this would be a very typical situation in which you would use a [ModelFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

The approach used in your forms.py would be appropriate if img_1 and img_2 were actual fields of class Item, but a ModelFormSet is a better choice when dealing with a set of related models.

Consider the future case where you wish to allow users three images rather than two. Using a ModelFormSet, this would be a one *character* code alteration. If you want to collect ancillary information on the ItemImage class, this would also be a trivial change.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my speculation and pointing out the right path.

Comment: @tamakisquare Have been trying to wrap my head around this since yesterday. A working example of the above might help! Basically, I want to know how to use a model formset _along with_ the model form already being used on the page

Comment: @Anupam I wish I could help you here but it's been years since I last used Django for server-side rendering. All my Django code is for API only.